# create list from repeated pattern in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I would like to create a list in python3, which look like this:

```
L = [(0,(0,1,2,3,4)), (1, (5,6,7,8,9)),(2,(10,11,12,13,14))......)
```

lets call it `L= [(i,(j1,j2,j3,j4,j5),...)`

The important thing is that the pattern keep on repeating till the j5 reaches `740231`

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Another way, strictly comprehending:

```
L = [(i,tuple(range(i*5,i*5+5))) for i in range(740231//5+1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution using `enumerate` and `range`:

```
n = 5
k = 14

ranger = (range(i, i+n) for i in range(0, k, n))
L = list(enumerate(map(tuple, ranger)))

# [(0, (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)), (1, (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)), (2, (10, 11, 12, 13, 14))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generator function :

```
def gen():
   x = 0
   y = 0  
   while y < 740231:
       yield( (x, tuple(range(y,y+5)), ) )
       x += 1
       y += 5
```

---

```
>>> list(gen())
[(0, (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)), (1, (5, 6, 7, 8, 9)), (2, (10, 11, 12, 13, 14)) ... ]
```